# Hybris EmailService where configure credentials

Tags: email, smtp, sap-commerce-cloud, mail-server, smtp-auth

I'm using EmailService in order to send a basic email:

```
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String body = request.getParameter("body");
    EmailAddressModel fromAddress = modelService.create(EmailAddressModel.class);
    fromAddress.setDisplayName("test@test.es");
    fromAddress.setEmailAddress("test@test.es");
    List<EmailAddressModel> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    addresses.add(fromAddress);
    EmailMessageModel email = modelService.create(EmailMessageModel.class);
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setBody(body);
    email.setToAddresses(addresses);
    email.setFromAddress(fromAddress);
    email.setReplyToAddress("myaccount@gmail.com");
    modelService.save(email);
    emailService.send(email);
```

Where do I configure the password of "myaccount@gmail.com" in order to make the Hybris SMTP server authentificate with my personal mail and send the email?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure below parameters in `local.properties` file or you can change them in hac for runtime only.

```
mail.smtp.server         
mail.smtp.port       
mail.smtp.user       
mail.smtp.password       
mail.pop3.beforesmtp     
mail.pop3.password       
mail.pop3.server         
mail.pop3.user       
mail.from        
mail.replyto         
mail.use.tls
```

You can get more detail from [blog post](https://gunce.mkysoft.com/known-hybris-configurations/#email).

Comment: But what if I want 2 or more email configurations ? These properties only support 1 user right ?

Comment: Not posible OOTB. You can create your own service.